# Dynamic Field Excel Output PHP

Tags: php, mysql, excel

Say I have this table on SQL database :

```
+---------------+-----------------+-----------------+
| category      | name            | month           |
+---------------+-----------------+-----------------+
| Fruit         | Mango           |January          |
| Fruit         | Apple           |January          |
| Fruit         | Grape           |February         |
| Vegetable     | Tommato         |February         |
| Vegetable     | Cuccumber       |March            |
| Animal        | Chicken         |March            |
+---------------+-----------------+-----------------+
```

then I'd like to output an excel file dynamically using PHPExcel, something like this :

[image: Table Looks 1:]

so, because it's dynamic, whenever an update occurs on the database, then the excel output will follow :
SqlTable update :

```
+---------------+-----------------+-----------------+
| category      | name            | month           |
+---------------+-----------------+-----------------+
| Fruit         | Mango           |January          |
| Fruit         | Apple           |January          |
| Fruit         | Grape           |February         |
| Vegetable     | Tommato         |February         |
| Vegetable     | Cuccumber       |March            |
| Animal        | Chicken         |March            |
| Vegetable     | Onion           |April            |
| Animal        | Fish            |April            |
+---------------+-----------------+-----------------+
```

[image: Expected Excel Output after update :]

Is that possible to do this by using phpExcel ?

what i've tried :

```
public function excel()
    {
        $spreadsheet = new Spreadsheet();

        $month = $this->db
            ->select('month')
            ->distinct('category,name')
            ->order_by('category,name')
            ->get('mytable')->result_array();
        $data = $this->db
            ->select('category,name')
            ->order_by('category,name')
            ->get('mytable')->result_array();
        $col_data = 'b';
        $row_category = 1;
        $row_name = 2;
        foreach ($data as $d) {                     
            $sheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();
            $sheet->setCellValue($col_data.$row_category, $d['category']);
            $sheet->setCellValue($col_data.$row_name, $d['name']);
            $col_data++;
        }

        $col_month = 'a';
        $row_month = 3;
        foreach ($month as $m) {
            $sheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();
            $sheet->setCellValue($col_month.$row_month, $m['month']);
            $row_month++;
        }       

        $writer = new Xlsx($spreadsheet);
        $writer->save('hello world.xlsx');
    }
```

The result was like this :

[image: empty numbers and i can't figure it out how to merge the column field]

Please let me know how to do it

Comment: Yes is possible, what you have tried? and please use new version of PHPExcel : [PHPSpreadsheet](https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Comment: @SimoneRossaini I updated my question, please take a look

Comment: With this code which is output?